# How to combine multiple hard drives in ubuntu server?

Tags: hard-drive, merge

So I have my main hard drive at `C:\` which I installed Ubuntu Server 14 on. I have a second hard drive with nothing in it at `D:\` how can I combine them?

What I want:
`C:\` drive is 180 GB. and `D:\` drive by is 80 GB. I want a single drive with 260 GB.

Is thispossible? I'm using Ubuntu Server 14 on a virtual Machine using Windows.
It's not a fresh clean install, but I only used it to test stuff.

Comment: RAID is something completely different that allows you to increase speed or increase data safety with several disks ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID)). You can use `gparted` to address you problem, and should back up any important data before proceeding. (be really atentive to the warnings it gives you before pressing ok :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Ubuntu is a virtual machine it is installed on a virtual hard drive you created when creating the virtual machine not on either of your hard drives (which would not be named `C` or `D` under Ubuntu.

If you want to give Ubuntu the full 260 GB of space you have to install it natively and [JBOD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18901/recommended-storage-scheme-for-home-server-lvm-jbod-raid-5).
Else your Windows host system will always take up some space.